# Definindo limite para query com UNION no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Gostaria de saber como eu crio um limite para um query que utiliza `UNION` no MySQL, no meu caso eu quero definir o `LIMIT 5` para a seguinte query:

```
$friends_a = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id!='$user_q[id]' AND
id='$friends_1_q[user_one_id]') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM users WHERE
id!='$user_q[id]' AND id='$friends_1_q[user_two_id]')");
```

Já tentei com vários códigos que eu encontrei na internet e não consigo, o que eu devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso resolva

```
$friends_a = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id!='$user_q[id]' AND
id='$friends_1_q[user_one_id]') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM users WHERE
id!='$user_q[id]' AND id='$friends_1_q[user_two_id]') as tabela limit 5");
```

Comment: Não, não funcionou, retornou o query em branco.
O que se refere com 'tabela'?

Comment: tabela são os dados resultantes do UNION ALL, ou seja query1 UNION ALL query2 = tabela, então faço um SELECT para retornar todos os dados de tabela colocando o LIMIT 5.